# Refresh tokens: security & implementation

Tags: authentication, security, jwt, token, refresh-token

When a user is authenticated by the server, the server sends, **according to the most common implementation I found**(which is were my question stems from), sends BOTH access token and the refresh token to the client.

-- **My first questions is**:
What is the point of sending both tokens to the client if, to my understanding, we have the refresh token in the first place to help us mitigate the consequences of an access token being leaked?

If both tokens are sent to the client and are stored together (in the same place, localStorage, sessionStorage, one in former, one in latter - I don't think it matters to the questions how we decide to store them on the client), if an attacker manages to steal the access token, then it is safe to assume he would also find a way to steal the refresh token from the same client since they are most likely stored together. I don't understand why most implementations and answers I find online mention sending both tokens to the client since its basically like putting all eggs in the same basket.
(A big part of my confusion comes also from the fact that those answers and implementations don't mention anything about storing the tokens in HttpOnly cookies, which I'd think would be a common practice if we want to prevent tokens getting leaked, so I'm getting a feeling I'm missing something)

-- **My second question would be**:
Would it be a correct solution then to persist the access and refresh tokens upon issue in an "accessT <-> refreshT"(like a key=value pair) table on a server, so that only one token is ever sent to the client - the access token? And when that access token expires the process of "refreshing" would be the following:

- ResServer = resource server
- AuthServer = authorization server

1. The request with the expired token is sent to the ResServer.
2. ResServer checks and sees that the access token has expired.
3. ResServer then sends a request to the AuthServer to look up the refresh token by the access token in the table mention above.
4. If AuthServer finds a refresh token by using the expired access token as a key - good, AuthServer generates a new access token.
5. AuthServer then responds to the ResServer with that new access token.
6. Having received a positive response, ResServer proceeds on with it's usual flow for authorized users.

^^ This seems to me to be a more rational way of keeping the refresh token safe - making it serve its primary function, which is why I don't understand why most other implementations on the web always mention sending both tokens to the client.

-- **And my third question is**:
Not having much experience implementing microservices, I am confused about why we would ever  prefer to implement this token back and forth approach, when, from what I understand, the entire point of tokens is that they are supposed to be a stateless solution(well, the refresh token is always kept on the server regardless of implementation, which confuses me even more about that "stateless" part). Doesn't it make more sense to just use cookies that basically serve the same function, but are easier to implement, secure by default("Secure", "HttpOnly" flags), and, as it appears to me, are much easier to revoke in can they are leaked?

Thanks you for taking your time to read this entire post, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding your first question:**
The advantage of having two tokens is not that you can store one of the tokens more securely. The advantage is that if the Resource Server gets compromised, it does not allow lateral escalation. For this to make sense, your access tokens must be bound to specific resource servers.

As an example, assume you have two resource servers ResA and ResB. Then your Authentication server would allow you to obtain one access token for each of these servers, and one refresh token (that allows refreshing both access tokens). If resource server A gets compromised (or the network path between the client and that server), then the access token to that server will expire at some point, and the attacker will not be able to access resource server B with the access token issued for resource server A. At the same time, only the legitimate user is able to refresh their tokens, since they only provide the refresh token to the AuthServer, such that a compromised or malicious resource server never sees at.

**That leads directly to your second question:**
Your proposed model prevents key rollover. If a resource server gets compromised, all its tokens are eternally compromised, unless the Authentication Server voids all refresh tokens. Voiding refresh tokens would lead to users being logged out of all resource servers (even those who are not compromised).

As an example, consider the following scenario: Tour authentication provider is a large public service, such as "Sign in with Google", with thousands of resource servers using this service. Now one of those resource servers gets compromised, and attackers steal the authentication tokens.

In the commonly employed auth-refresh token pattern, the auth tokens will expire, which means that the service will be inaccessible for attackers as soon as the used vulnerability is fixed + the time it takes for tokens to expire (since the attackers could not get hold of the resource tokens), without the need for the AuthServer to do anything. Additionally, the AuthServer does not need to keep track of the issued tokens, if it uses cryptography to sign the tokens with a private key only known to the auth server, as it (and all resource servers) can trivially verify token authenticity by validating against a public key (please also see the end of my answer).

In your proposed approach, the AuthServer (which is Google in this example) would have to void all refresh tokens OR they would have to selectively delete all auth-refresh token pairs for the affected resource server from the key-value store. That key-value store will be gigantic, since it has to contain EVERY auth token ever issued, for any service that uses "Sign in with Google", and apart from storage costs, this delete operation will take quite some time.

**Regarding your last question:**
You can store access tokens in Cookies. There is a bunch of advantages to that (including the Secure and HttpOnly flags that you mentioned). It has two disadvantages: If you want to implement something like a CLI client that runs outside of a browser, you would have to implement Cookie handling. The other disadvantage is the CSRF risk as Cookies are automatically sent on every request. Using local storage prevents this, as an external website cannot access the local storage of your website to extract the token.
In the end it comes down to the concrete scenario, if Cookies or Local Storage + Custom Header are the preferable solution.

However, I think you have a misconception regarding statefulness:
Access and Refresh tokens do not need to be stored on the server. Instead, the Auth Server signs the Token Contents with a cryptographic private key, before sending them to a client. In doing so, the AuthServer includes an expiration date in the token, which is included in the signed content.

To validate the token, the Resource Server (or the AuthServer) checks if the signature comes from the AuthServer's private key, and then checks if the expiration date has passed. In particular, the resource server does not need to communicate with the AuthServer, apart from obtaining its Public Key from time to time. This makes this solution scale really well for very large deployments. See [the Microsoft Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens), which do a great job on explaining the difference between Auth and Refresh tokens.

What you are alluding to are traditional session ids, which are stored on the server until they expire. Thats obviously a much simpler solution, and works well for smaller, more monolithic applications. It just does not work for hyper scalers.

Comment: Appreciate your thorough answer as there is a lot useful information I haven't thought about, however, after going over it a few times, I feel like it doesn't address exactly my question: at some point you mention `Only the legitimate user is able to refresh their tokens, since they only provide the refresh token to the AuthServer, such that a compromised resource server never sees it` and `the auth tokens will expire, which means that the service will be inaccessible for attackers as soon as the vulnerability is fixed`, and later `since the attackers couldn't get hold of the resource tokens`.

Comment: -- These scenarios presuppose that the attacker never managed to get a hold of a refresh token, but I think it's reasonable to assume the following: If we are sending both tokens to the user we can imagine that an attacker could managed to inject a js script and steal those tokens stored in client's browser storage and now could send that refresh token to the AuthServer, and the AuthServer would not be able to distinguish between the legitimate user and the attacker since the attacker now has the that same refresh token we sent to the user initially along with the access token.

Comment: If you suppose the attacker has control over the client to the point where they can read local storage, then its game over anyways. At this point the attacker could also inject a script that does not only steal credentials, but directly instruct the victims browser to perform malicious actions. In other words: You are right in that the split between Auth and Refresh token fixes one specific attack vector, but not any attack vector.